# how can i plot a graph in in vb to to show a large amount of data

Tags: vb.net, graph, plot

I  want  to  plot  graph to show the difference of Net connectivity in one hour . i found the average speed of One hour and the different between the Speed. and i add the difference percentage in a ListBox . I have to show the numbers in graph of one hour  ? How can I Plot the Graph Any  Suggestion Please .

```
enter code here

  Dim Per As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        Per = Math.Abs((avg - Val(ListBox2.Items.Item(x).ToString)) / (avg)) * 100
        ListBox3.Items.Add(Per)
```

i have to plot all the number of ListBox3 contains more than 3000.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301982

Comment: i can not understand

Comment: is there any other method which help me

Comment: either use excel, or use .net's chart controls http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series

Comment: s.Points.AddXY(0, Val(ListBox3.Items.Item(1).ToString))                         
  s.Points.AddXY(1, Val(ListBox3.Items.Item(2).ToString))                            i am using like this ... i want to set the loop for  all the item in the listbox.     can any suggestion ??

Answer (score 2):

i found it...

```
For y As Integer = 0 To ListBox3.Items.Count - 1
    s.Points.AddXY(y, Val(ListBox3.Items.Item(y).ToString))
 Next
    Chart1.Series.Add(s)
```